# PHP Files Throw Parse Errors (ex: T_STRING) After Migrating

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding, vagrant, line-endings

This is a weird one, and something I've never run into before. 
I'm deploying to a `vvv` (Varying Vagrant Vagrants) box from PHPStorm, and the project is a wordpress site.

Frequently, when files are moved over, after reloading the site, I get a PHP parse error, always at the last line of the file. The file isn't necessarily the one I opened and edited, and adding a `?>` to the end fixes it. I can then immediately *remove* the `?>` at the end of the file, and all remains well. 
This occurs intermittently, making it very difficult to isolate and fix.

An example parse error would be something like:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting end of file in /srv/www/cpr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/3rd-party/class.jetpack-amp-support.php on line 359
```

The specific parse error changes; it's not always the same thing, but it is always fixed by simply adding a `?>`, refreshing, etc.

I keep thinking this has to be something to do with either line endings or encoding, but both *seem* to be ok. (PHPStorm using `LF` and `UTF-8`.

The only part of this workflow that is new to me, is the `vvv` box, as I've previously used other vendors' vagrant boxes, but I'm not sure how that would cause this.

Is something being appended to these files that's breaking when PHP goes to parse them? Is git or vagrant or PHPStorm's deployment overriding line ending rules and changing them?
I'm at a total loss.

Any help is greatly appreciated. As I roll out larger plugin changes, I'm unable to use the WP api, or do anything else without manually opening all the affected files and adding PHP closing tags, then removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally track down the cause of this by isolating the various components. 
I ruled out phpStorm and git by migrating some files manually and getting the same error to occur above the app's root, on the vagrant box. This isolated the issue to the vvv box itself, and not the project, PHPStorm, or the deploy settings.

I then setup `git` to force linux line endings via a `.gitattributes` file in the repo root, with settings based on things I read [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420243/php-files-throw-parse-errors-ex-t-string-after-migrating).

Here's what I'm using now:

```
# Force provisioning script to use LF, even on Windows
* text eol=lf

# Avoid binary files to be corrupted by CRLF conversion
*.png binary
*.gif binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
```

I then used `dos2unix` and `find` to recursively fix all the line endings in the project, like so:

`find . -name '*.php' |xargs dos2unix`

So far - all is well, and persisting. I'll update if this pops back up and needs further revision.

Comment: Two years later, and this fix has held with the same project plus new ones that have come on board, across all environments and repos.